# regular expressions multiple statements

Tags: php, regex

I have half my problem working. The problem is: I need to match words that are either 7 letters long and starting with st OR 9 letters long ending with tion. I have code that works for the first half of the question: `st\w{5}\s`. This will match a 7 letter word such as 'startin' in the example: start startin starting.

However I cant seem to add the second half. `(st\w{5}\s)|(tion\w{5})` Does not work in trying to find 'startin' and 'attention' out of: start startin starting attention. 
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `(st\w{5})|(\w{5}tion)` o_o ?

Comment: So you spell _attention_ starting with "tion" and then five more letters …?

Comment: shouldn't the second part be `\w{5}tion$`? Damn, i hate being ninj'd.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look for the word boundaries `\b(?:(st\w{5})|(\w{5}tion))\b`

[image]

Comment: **+1** Nice image, will maybe use something similar in my future answers :)

Comment: @ HamZa, Thank you. I found those to be much easier to follow then typing out a full explanation of each symbol.

Answer (score 2):

use word boundaries, for example:

```
\b(st[a-z]{5}|[a-z]{5}tion)\b
```